# Hibernation interrupt on Razer Blade 15" Advanced running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, laptop, hibernate

I am trying to get hibernation to work on my installation of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS which is installed on a Razer Blade Advanced (early 2022). I am currently using kernel version is `6.0.0`. Previously I was using `5.17.15`, on which I was only able to get hibernation working from the CLI.

Currently, I am only able to run a successful hibernation (either from closing the lid or from the CLI running `sudo systemctl hibernate`) if it is performed twice in a row. I would like to get `suspend-then-hibernate` working to preserve battery life. This command currently doesn't successfully complete at all.

Turning on `pci=nomsi` in the kernel parameters resolves the issue for both CLI and lid instantiated hibernations, but unfortunately has a tendency to crash the system.

So far I have done the following:

- allocated and assigned a `/swapfile` and updated the kernel parameters to check for the `resume` and `resume_offset`
- disabled all wake-up devices (one named `PXSX` refuses to turn off)
- set `button.lid_init_state=open` to prevent suspend loops associated with this laptop
- tried both `s2idle` and `deep` mem_sleep types
- denylisted the NVIDIA driver from loading

This is an overview of the status of each command permutation:

*With* `pci=nomsi`:

- hibernate **(success)**
- suspend-then-hibernate **(success)**

*Without* `pci=nomsi`:

- hibernate -> hibernate **(success)**
- hibernate -> suspend-then-hibernate **(fail)**
- suspend-then-hibernate -> suspend-then-hibernate **(fail)**
- suspend-then-hibernate -> hibernate **(success)**

---

##### Potentially relevant command outputs:

```
➜  ~ grep . /sys/bus/*/devices/*/power/wakeup
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPWRBN:00/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0A:03/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0D:01/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0E:00/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1A58201B:00/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:06.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:06.2/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.3/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.0/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:01.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:02.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:03.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:3a:00.0/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:6e:00.0/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/platform/devices/ACPI000E:00/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/platform/devices/alarmtimer.0.auto/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/platform/devices/INTC1070:00/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/platform/devices/rtc_cmos/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/0-0/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/domain0/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-10/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4/power/wakeup:disabled
```

```
➜  ~ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enabled
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:04:00.0
```

```
➜  ~ free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        16059020     1592612    11627868      966844     2838540    13180228
Swap:       20971516           0    20971516
```

---

##### Logs

###### Hibernate -> hibernate (successful)

###### `sudo systemctl hibernate` (first run - fail):

https://pastebin.com/mbxNkrBa

###### `sudo systemctl hibernate` (second run - success):

https://pastebin.com/hn4fujLG

###### Hibernate -> suspend-then-hibernate (fail)

###### `sudo systemctl hibernate` (first run - fail)

https://pastebin.com/FJ6PEh8f

###### `sudo systemctl suspend-then-hibernate` (second run- fail)

https://pastebin.com/MWfKp7yU

###### With `pci=nomsi`

###### `sudo systemctl suspend-then-hibernate` (success)

https://pastebin.coclm/VqBqZsfh

###### `sudo systemctl hibernate` (success)

https://pastebin.com/53mCBNHw

---

Thank you! I will gladly provide any more command outputs and/or logs.

Comment: Where did you get a kernel version 6 from?

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the discrete thunderbolt support in the BIOS and this seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: +1 on disabling thunderbolt support for solving the suspend issue- it was automatically resuming.